# Cómo acelerar el buffering en videos en HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, video

Tengo un problema con los vídeos que inserto en una página web a través de la etiqueta `<video>`. Resulta que cuando quiero reproducir el video en un móvil, el buffering del vídeo es malo, es decir, no avanza y como consecuencia el vídeo se pausa.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema? ¿Instalar un servidor de streaming de vídeo podría solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sé que esto no va a solucionar el problema del buffering exactamente, pero puedes jugar un poco con la etiqueta `video` (o con `source`) para especificar diferentes vídeos dependiendo del dispositivo que esté usando el usuario. Mientras menos pese el fichero, antes de descargará, evitando el problema del buffering.

Así tendrías varias versiones del mismo vídeo, por ejemplo: una para móvil (de menos calidad y resolución y menos tamaño), otra para tableta (con calidad/resolución media y un tamaño algo mayor) y otra para computadores (con calidad/resolución óptima y un tamaño mucho mayor).

Entonces usarías [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-media) en la etiqueta `resource` para indicar qué video debe tomarse en cada caso. Por ejemplo:

```
<video>
  <source src="video-movil.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width: 480px)"> 
  <source src="video-medio.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width: 768px)"> 
  <source src="video-grande.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

En el código de arriba, el video tomaría como fuente video-movil-mp4 en dispositivos con una pantalla de ancho máximo 480px; si no, si la pantalla tuviera hasta un máximo de 768px tomaría video-medio.mp4; y en cualquier otro caso (pantallas de más de 768px) usaría video-grande.mp4.

El principal inconveniente: aunque parece que su soporte está extendido, en Safari para iOS (en iPhone o iPad) y en Opera Mobile puede presentar problemas porque no parece estar soportado según [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource) o MDN:

[image: soporte de media queries en source]

---

Fuentes y Bibliografía (en inglés):

- [Especificación HTML: descripción de `source`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element).
- [MDN: Etiqueta `<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source).
- [CSS Tricks: Video Source by Screen Size](https://css-tricks.com/video-source-by-screen-size/).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin duda puede solucionar el problema, pero también debo de preocuparme para la calidad del vídeo, así que checaré otras alternativas. :D